# Swift extensions does not work in tests when SDK is in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I have SDK **A** in Objective-C which works fine. I’ve created extensions for it and it still works on production code.

When I started test my code and I use SDK directly everything is fine. My tests fail when I call my extension with stacktrace:
`file:///%3Cunknown%3E: test failure: SomeTests.testAExtension() failed: failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", “-[A myFun()]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001a8d3e0…`

This is code which I use:

```
// sdk class in Objective-C
class A {
    func sdkFun() {
        // do something
    }
}

extension A {
    func myFun() {
        sdkFun()
    }
}

class SomeTests {

    // O.K.
    func testAFun() {
        let a = A()
        a.sdkFun()
    }

    // Fails with error
    func testA() {
        let a = A()
        a.myFun()
    }
}
```

What do I wrong?
I use Swift 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Use **@objc** in front of your `extension` in `swift` file. like below

```
@objc extension A {
    func myFun() {
        sdkFun()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@objc with public function and extension and your class. like this way

```
@objc public class A {
  @objc public func sdkFun() {
    // do something
  }
}
@objc public extension A {
  @objc public func myFun() {
    sdkFun()
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my anwer @jczerski you need to add public access specifier as well. with your class and extension.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Can share you codebase? Because it’s working for me.